# Is there a way to implement this .csv reader without using return in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner in Haskell (and StackOverflow for that matter). I wanted some suggestions on how to optimize my csv reader, especially since I was told in a tutorial that explicit `return` is not idiomatic. My implementation:

```
convertCSVFile :: String -> IO (V.Vector StockSummary)
convertCSVFile fileName = do
    csvData <- BL.readFile fileName
    case decode HasHeader csvData :: Either String (V.Vector StockSummary) of 
        Left err -> error err
        Right v -> return v
```

Comment: I don't see what you could actually do here instead of the `return` (or its synonym, `pure`, if you prefer). `return` in Haskell is *not* related to the imperative keyword of the same name in most languages - in Haskell it's a function which "wraps" a "normal" value in a Monadic "box" (here the Monad is `IO`).

Comment: ‘I was told in a tutorial that explicit `return` is not idiomatic’ — which tutorial was this? As far as I’m aware, explicit `return` is completely idiomatic in Haskell, and as you see here, there are many situations in which it is easiest to use `return` rather than anything else.

Comment: I was reading Real World Haskell and I found this excerpt:

```Haskell doesn’t have a return keyword, because a function is a single expression, not a sequence of statements. The value of the expression is the result of the function. (Haskell does have a function called return, but we won’t discuss it for a while; it has a different meaning than in imperative languages.)```
I think I got confused by that thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I have voted to close as "not reproducible" because the stated goal (avoid `return`) came from a misunderstanding of RWH, and it seems unlikely that fixes to that misunderstanding generalize well to other readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allergic to monadic operations (return and bind), you can write this point-free with `Data.Either.either`:

```
convertCSVFile :: String -> IO (V.Vector StockSummary)
convertCSVFile = 
  fmap (either error id . decode hasHeader) 
  . BL.readFile
```

But I certainly wouldn't say this is easier to read than what you originally wrote.

Comment: It's unlikely to be an issue, but do note that this has very slightly different behavior than the original. There are two differences: first, on failure, this produces an `IO` action that executes successfully, and only produces an `error` when its result is evaluated, whereas the original produces an `IO` action that errors out during execution; second, on success, executing this does not evaluate the `decode` call, whereas the original does. (The first corresponds to `error err` vs `return (error err)` and the second to `case ... of ... -> return foo` vs `return $ case ... of ...`.)